# PHP access variable from included file

Tags: php, include

have a file like so:

```
<?php
require_once "properties.php";
$GLOBALS["to_home"] = "../sfair";
echo tohome () . "index.php";
?>
```

And properties.php:

```
<?php
function tohome()
{
if(isset($GLOBALS['to_home']))
{
return $GLOBALS['to_home'] . "/";
}
else
{
return "';
}
}
```

Which should give me `../stair/index.php`.
But instead gives me `index.php`.
How can I make the included file be able to access the variables of the including files?
note: I found another answer ("unable to access global variable from included file" but it did not work.

Comment: I see a syntax error in your example a " does not match a ' in: return "';

Comment: Aside from the incorrect quote (which I assume to be a typo here only), your code should work just fine. Is there more to this that you have not posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you send the `$GLOBALS["to_home"]` with the Function call? That's what functions are for...

`echo tohome($GLOBALS["to_home"]) . "index.php";`

Of course you will have to change the function contents, but I guess you will get the idea.

Comment: yes. in properties.php I would have to add a default definition for $to_home, and then instead of checking is set I would check if $to_home is equal to that default value. It worked.